# WiFi not working on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, intel-wireless

I have an [ASUS K501LX](https://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks/K501LX/), that has a [Wireless-ac 7265](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/dual-band-wireless-ac-7265.html). I've just installed Ubuntu 15.10, but I can't enable WiFi. I guess it's because of drivers. I have read many posts and articles about people having the same problems on Ubuntu, but I still can't get it working. I have some drivers on Intel's website but I'm not able to install it. How should I proceed in attempting to install drivers for my wireless card?

Result of rfkill list all

```
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Result of dmesg | grep iwl

```
[    2.170941] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    2.197025] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.217697] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.226666] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.231556] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.231587] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.380682] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.30.14.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.575281] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    2.575437] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.575666] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.598957] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    2.601838] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 i have edited, please take a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your wireless is hard blocked:yes which means that the wireless switch or key combination is set to turn the wireless radio off. In the case of a number of Asus laptops, the kernel doesn't correctly recognize key presses, perhaps Fn+F2. Let's try to get the key presses working as expected. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
exit
```

Reboot and see if your wireless is working after you manipulate the wireless key combination.

If the above does not work, redo it again but replace asus_nb_wmi wapf=1 with asus_nb_wmi wapf=4, reboot and check again.

Also, you can get later firmware to possibly improve wireless performance. With a working internet connection, please do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware.git
cd iwlwifi-firmware/firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265*  /lib/firmware
```

Reboot.

Comment: Just for the benefit of the searchers, was it `wapf=1` or was it `wapf=4` that worked for your Asus K501LX?

Comment: it was wapf=1 that helped me :)