# Wireless card RT3290

Tags: wireless, ralink, wifi-hardware-switch

I have got problem with Wireless card RT3290. I have laptop ASUS X550LC with card RT3290 and I can't connect with internet.

I know that problem is:
Code:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

My combine keys Fn+F2 don't working.
Set default settings in BIOS also don't working.

In blacklist.conf I don't have f.e. rt2800pci

*lspci -vnn | grep Network :*

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
```

*iwconfig :*

```
wlp3s0f0  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          
enp2s0f1  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Thanks for your time

## EDIT:

*lsmod | grep asus*

```
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
asus_wireless          16384  0
wmi                    24576  3 asus_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  45056  3 asus_wmi,i915,nouveau
```

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe -r asus_nb_wmi && sudo rfkill unblock all`.

Comment: unfortunetely, hard blocked is still "yes"

Comment: Please try the technique here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/744774/wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu-15-10/744849#744849 You won't need the firmware step, however.

Comment: I tried with asus_nb_wmi wapf=1 and asus_nb_wmi wapf=4 and it didn't help

Comment: With a reboot each time and trying Fn+F2 after each reboot?

Comment: Yes, but now, soft blocked is always no :/ It looks like Fn+F2 stopped work

Comment: Now, I did this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558&p=12819607#post12819607, and tried again with wapf=1 and wapf=4, and soft blocked is yes/no, but hard blocked is still only yes

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `lsmod | grep asus`

Comment: done :) I know that this card often have a problem :/

Comment: Anyone have suggestion?